# Flex 3 sorting object fields

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, object, field

I have an object in **ActionScript3** code, which I need to sort.

I iterate through the object and print out each value:

```
for (var i:String in columnData) {
```

However I need the data I am iterating to be sorted alphabetically. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only sort Array/Lists, not fields in an object.

If you want a sorted order, you first need to iterate thru the object and push the values in an array/list and *then* sort it.

**[Edit]:** OK, so I assumed you just needed the data. No, flex doesn't provide a hashmap (like a TreeMap ala Java). What you could do is to store the name value pairs as objects in an array. Array provides a `SortOn()` method to let you sort on a specific field.

Comment: my problem is that the object contains name:value pairs so i cant just put into an arraylist

Comment: does flex provide any other datatype for storing name:value pairs , e.g like a hashmap in Java?

Answer (score 1):

The [ActionScript Foundry](http://www.servebox.org/actionscript-foundry/actionscript-foundry-documentation/the-collections-framework/) has an AS implementation of some of the Java collections--looks like you could find what you need there.